# How can i translate "Please fill the code shown" in Chinese?

Tags: grammar

I have to create a website for China, and i have a sentence to translate which is :

> Please fill the code shown

This message is followed by a Captcha Code.

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

请填写验证码。if the blank is on the left of the code.请填写右侧验证码 would be better

Answer (score 0):

**Traditional Chinese Version:**
請在這裡填寫顯示的代碼

**Simplified Chinese Version:**
请在这里填写显示的代码